# Fixed size tablerow on tablelayout android

Tags: android, layout

i'm trying to create a table layout, and i found a problem to set fixed size on it

here's my layout:

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1" android:background="#ffffff">

 <TableRow 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 

    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tvpar" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textSize="18dp" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="18dip" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:textColor="#000"/> 

        </TableRow> 

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#cccccc" />


        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 

        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"> 
            <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tvyes"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/> 
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"> 

        <View
         android:layout_width="1dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:background="#cccccc"/>
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"> 
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvno" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
       </TableRow>

    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>        

    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="1dp" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#cccccc"> 
    </TableLayout>       


    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="#ffffff">

      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/btnnext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:scaleType="center"
      android:src="@drawable/next_a" /> 
        </TableLayout>  
    </TableRow> 

</TableLayout>
```

and this is the result :

http://i780.photobucket.com/albums/yy82/WalkThis_Way/a2_zps3439009c.png

and i need to fixed size of table row , the result i'm looking for is like this :

http://i780.photobucket.com/albums/yy82/WalkThis_Way/Untitled2_zpse20bb477.png

Answer (score 0):

try this,it will give what you want:

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1" android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">



    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

        <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tvpar" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textSize="18dp" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="18dip" 
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:textColor="#000"/> 

        </TableRow> 

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#cccccc" />


        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 

        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"> 
            <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tvyes"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/> 
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"> 

        <View
         android:layout_width="1dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:background="#cccccc"/>
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"> 
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvno" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
       </TableRow>

    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>        

    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="1dp" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#cccccc"> 
    </TableLayout>       


    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="#ffffff">

      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/btnnext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:scaleType="center"
      android:src="@drawable/next_a" /> 
        </TableLayout>  

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: still have problem with next arrow image, the problem is image position is in under tablelayout